# Integrating conical surfaces and Divergence Theorem

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

[image]

I am currently working through this question. This is how I have approached (a) however I am thrown by the negative sign, can somebody point out my mistake(s)?

[image]

For (b) I have used Divergence/Gauss' theorem. I got $-0.75\pi$ where $s(u,v)$ was the same as the one used in (a). I believe (c) is (b)-(a)?

*EDIT: I have missed u from the z component of **N**, this gives me an answer of -$\pi/3$

Comment: When using Gauss' theorem, you need to have three dimensions to integrate over, but $s(u,v)$ only provides two.

Comment: user43290: Which book did u get this question from?

Answer (score 1):

Your normal vector isn't a unit normal (divide by $\sqrt{2}$), also I am fairly certain it is an inward pointing normal rather than an outward pointing one.

If your updated answer of $-\pi/3$ is computationally correct then the actual answer should be$\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}$.

Note: It's been a good couple of years since I looked at a vector calculus question so I hope my thinking is right, apologies if it isn't.

Comment: Normalisation is not necessary when expressed as the user has done (with cross product) - the normalisation factor for the normal is cancelled by the scaling factor for the area.